# In "The Silver Linings Playbook", what is on the business card at 55:04?

Tags: silver-linings-playbook

I'm watching the Silver Linings Playbook on a mobile device and am curious about the scene where Pat goes to Tiffany's house and another man hastily drives up, interrupted a conversation and offers his business card.

The camera zooms in on the card but I can't make out the text. I don't think it played a role in being a plot device, but I can imagine a few ways this is connected.

Can anyone see (perhaps in HD) see what this card says?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be plot related...just a standard business card for what appears to be "Jordie Timmonn" ... unfortunately, the job title is not easy to discern.

[image]